# WKWebView history loading

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am working on a small app to learn `WKWebView` abilities. I have added a navigation bar at the bottom with back and forward buttons in order to navigate between loaded pages. But if I initialize the view with `loadHTMLString` instead of `loadRequest`, then the history buttons are not working. The `canGoBack/canGoForward` attribute is false.

Is it possible to navigate between loaded html documents in `WKWebView` if they were loaded with `loadHTMLString`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the documentation, the built in history that ships with `WKWebView` supports URLs but not blobs of HTML. Have a look at [`WKBackForwardListItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKBackForwardListItem_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/WKBackForwardListItem). It has three properties: `title`, `URL`, and `initialURL`.

You could build this functionality yourself, by implementing a similar list and a similar model. I don't know if `WKBackForwardListItem` is subclassable, but you can make your own.